# Resources in a C++ Metro Style Application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a library made in C++/GDI that I am trying to port to C++/Metro Style.

The functions `FindResource`/`LoadResource`/(...) are not available in *Metro Style Applications*, and the documentation for this topic says:

> <sup>[Dev Center - Metro style apps > Docs > Developing games > Developing
>   Metro style DirectX and C++ apps > Defining app resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994921.aspx)</sup>
>
> This material is not yet available. This placeholder topic is provided
>   as an example of documentation that may be included in a later
>   release.

Has anyone found any other source of information on how to deal with resources in a C++ Metro Style App?

I am specifically looking for a way to store a font file as a resource with my application package and load it programmatically as a stream.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything that corresponds directly to Win32-style resources. At least from what I've seen so far (admittedly, not a lot) larger resources are doing in Local Storage, and smaller stuff in Local Settings.

Comment: You can not store font file in the resource in Metro. Metro uses file based deployment model, i.e you should add font file to your project and it will get packaged with your app as part of the build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metro has a ResourceManager class that can be used to access resources. Here is an example to get a file from the Assets folder -

```
auto file = ResourceManager::Current->MainResourceMap->GetSubtree("Files")->GetValue("Assets/Logo.png");
```

Here is a link to accessing resources in a Metro app -

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694557.aspx

Comment: I am afraid I cannot use this solution, since [ResourceManager is a class from .Net Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx), and I am developing a native C++ library.

Comment: WinRT has a ResourceManager class. The code in my post is an extract from a Metro app that I created using XAML and C++/CX.

Answer (score 2):

Check [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/340084/Under-the-hood-Part-4-Cplusplus-WinRT-Component-DL) about component DLLs in WinRT.

Apparently and base solely on the author of this article:

> The interesting part here is that C++ applications is XAML based. No more .RC and resource.h files in C++ (for metro).

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: This goes in the right direction, although it leaves many questions unanswered. In .Net you can use resource ids inside XAML files, and you can also access those resources programmatically using ResourceManager class. It is not clear for me how to achieve the same in a C++/Metro Style App